# yii2 load model in controller doesnt load Form's posted data

Tags: php, model-view-controller, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

This is my view file and it has one form that should post a file with a text variable data of 0000000005. But for some reason the load function inside the controller does not populate these data.

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $model backend\models\customs\UploadForm */
/* @var $form ActiveForm */
?>

<div class="vendor_file_upload_form">

    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(
        ['id' => 'form-files'],
        ['options' => ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']]
    ); ?>

        <?= $form->field($model, 'AppFile')->fileInput() ?>

        <?= $form->field($model,'apid')->textInput(); ?>

        <div class="form-group">
            <?= Html::submitButton(Yii::t('app', 'Submit'), ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
        </div>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

</div><!-- vendor_file_upload_form -->
```

This is my controller

```
public function actionFiles($id=null)
{
    $model = new UploadForm();

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()))
    {
        $model->AppFile = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'AppFile');

        if ($model->upload())
        {
            \Yii::$app->getSession()->setFlash('success', 'File has been successfully uploaded.');
            return $this->redirect(['index']);
        }
        else
        {
            \Yii::$app->getSession()->setFlash('error', 'Wrong File Format , Try proper format.');
            return $this->redirect(['index']);
        }
    }
}
```

I found that for some reason Load data does not load all the posted form parameters. I have spent 3 hours and I am still unable to understand why my form data is not being transferred properly.

I checked the Payload and I found following which means my data is coming fine but load function is not loading properly.

> ------WebKitFormBoundaryZfszVA0IZuj02ZFT Content-Disposition: form-data; name="_csrf-backend"
>
> UEZaLmZ4MzEWExBjLz8LSWAnHG9SGgFhaBcqbycRZWc1dGtCAD9JYg==
>   ------WebKitFormBoundaryZfszVA0IZuj02ZFT Content-Disposition: form-data; name="UploadForm[AppFile]"
>
> ------WebKitFormBoundaryZfszVA0IZuj02ZFT Content-Disposition: form-data; name="UploadForm[AppFile]"; filename="falcon-wallpaper.jpg"
>   Content-Type: image/jpeg
>
> ------WebKitFormBoundaryZfszVA0IZuj02ZFT Content-Disposition: form-data; name="UploadForm[apid]"
>
> 0000000005
>   ------WebKitFormBoundaryZfszVA0IZuj02ZFT--

EDIT:
Below is my model file,

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * Date: 1/8/2017
 * Time: 9:52 PM
 */

namespace backend\models\customs;

use backend\models\ApplicationFiles;
use yii\base\Model;
use yii\web\UploadedFile;

/**
 * UploadForm is the model behind the upload form.
 */
class UploadForm extends Model
{
    /**
     * @var UploadedFile
     */
    public $AppFile; //files which needs to be uploaded
    public $apid; //application_id

    /**
     * @return array the validation rules.
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['apid'], 'required','message'=>'No Application Id found'],
            [['AppFile'], 'file', 'skipOnEmpty' => false, 'extensions' => 'png, jpg'],

        ];
    }


    public function upload()
    {
        //upload on the backed/uploads folder with time stamp as the file name
        if ($this->validate()) {

            $File_name = time() . '.' . $this->AppFile->extension;

            if($this->AppFile->saveAs(\Yii::$app->basePath.'/uploads/' .$File_name ))
            {
                $model = new ApplicationFiles();
                $model->name = $File_name;
                $model->path = \Yii::$app->basePath.'/uploads/' .$File_name;
                $model->application_id = $this->apid;
               // $model->type =
                $model->save();
            }

            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: can you share UploadForm model code ?

Comment: I edited the code and added model file please check now. Its a simple file uploader model which takes also an application id in apid.

Comment: you get solution or still searching solution ? I think you have to add AppFile in safe

Comment: I am still searching for the solution ,  I have explicitly call the post method like this to load the variable.   
$model->apid =  Yii::$app->request->post("UploadForm")["apid"];
$model->AppFile = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'AppFile');

I am not sure why load function doesn't work at all otherwise for more variables i need to explicitly call assign each variable like this.

Comment: @Govind your awesome thanks alot, I tried "Safe" validator for the AppFile and everything works fine now. Load function is now loading the apid without any issue. But I dont get it what is the logic behind.

Comment: I think this link help you http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/161/understanding-safe-validation-rules/ This is yii1.1 wiki but the logic are same :)

Comment: @Govind cheers, I had forgetten to add the name attribute to the safe list, works perfectly